# Is it possible to have a where with a select statement which you add wildcards to

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, wildcard

I have a situation where I need to use a select statement in a where but then also append and prepend wildcards to the value it returns. E.g something like:

```
select * from [Customers.customervisibility] where userId like '%,' (Select Id from [Users.Users] where name ='MyName') ',%'
```

but running this gives:

> Incorrect syntax near ',%'.

Now the `Select` Statement is only ever going to return 1 id, so I don't know if there is a better way to write it maybe using a function.

The overall goal is so that I can select the rows from `[customer.customervisibility]` where the id is contained in a comma seperated string column `[UserId]`

e.g. if `id = 8`

I need to get the rows where `*,8,*...`

It has to be inline, I cannot use variable, and you will have to excuse the TERRIBLE database design. this is so that it will work with third party software

Comment: don't you just need to concatenate the strings? `where userId like '%,'+ (select....) + ',%'`

Comment: If I do this I get: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%,' to data type int.` and the column `UserId` is an `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server.. Well actually its Azure Sql, but same difference

Comment: USE convert(VARCHAR(100),userId) like '%'+(Select Id from [Users.Users] where name ='MyName')+'%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `where` clause

If your DBMS support `Concat` the use this.

```
userId like concat('%' ,(Select top 1 cast(Id as varchar(50)) from [Users.Users] where name ='MyName') ,'%')
```

Else

```
userId like '%' +(Select top 1 cast(Id as varchar(50)) from [Users.Users] where name ='MyName') +'%'
```

I have used `Top 1` to avoid sub-query returns more than one row error if in case your subquery returns more than one row

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from [Customers.customervisibility] where convert(VARCHAR(100),userId) like '%'+(Select Id from [Users.Users] where name ='MyName')+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        *
FROM            [Customers.customervisibility]
WHERE        (userId LIKE '%  , Select Id from [Users.Users]  where status="MyName"     %')
```

Comment: This gives the error: `Incorrect syntax near 'MyName'.`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten the concatenation character `+` for strings. Try below query:

```
select * from [Customers.customervisibility] where userId like '%,'+(Select Id from [Users.Users] where name ='MyName')+',%'
```

This will give results whose `userId` contains your Id where `userId` is a comma separated string.